# AWS lambda PDF Filler integration

Tags: aws-lambda, pdf-generation

I am new to AWS. Can anyone tell me how to integrate PDFFiller using AWS lambda. I have seen one url. [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdffiller-lambda)

It is very easy to understand. But I don't know how to integrate. I did R&D but didn't get any urls. Can anyone provide some solutions or urls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Building Lambda functions with NodeJs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html)

We can deploy the lambda with dependencies as follows

**1 - Initialise the Node.js Project**

```
npm init
```

**2 - Install the PdfFiller package**

```
npm install pdffiller --save
```

**3 - Write your index.js file**

```js
const pdfFiller = require('pdffiller');

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {

    const sourcePDF = 'sample.pdf';
    var destinationPDF =  "/tmp/test_complete.pdf";

    var data = {
        "demo" : "demo-val"
    };

    pdfFiller.fillFormWithOptions( sourcePDF, destinationPDF, data, true,"/tmp",function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("In callback (we're done).");
    });
     


    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "success",
    };
    return response;
};
```

**4 - Make a zip**

You'll have project structure as

```
~/my-function
├── index.js
└── node_modules
    ├── pdffiller
```

Make your entire project as zip (should include node_modules)

**5 - Deploying**

And finally you can deploy it. See how to deploy as [zip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html)

### Factors to ensure

- **sourcePDF** : Currently, the source pdf has been put within the project itself. This is not a perfect method; you may load it from another source, such as s3, external storage, etc.
- **destinationPDF , /tmp as prefix** : The Lambda execution environment provides a file system for your code to use at `/tmp`. This space has a fixed size of `512 MB`. You can attach file system with your lambda when you need to store the destination pdf [See](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-aws-lambda-data-storage-options-in-web-apps/). Or another sources such as s3.
- **Why used `fillFormWithOptions`** : As the package `pdffiller` creating a temporary pdf file,([see index.js file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdffiller-lambda?activeTab=code)) unlike with the other fie system,lambda uses /tmp for storing the files (without any file-system attachment).
  It is necessary to mention the temporary pdf generate path with lambda. Else, the execution will fail at here, as it couldn't be able to create the temp pdf file.

Reference Links :

- [Building Lambda functions with NodeJs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html)
- [Choosing between AWS Lambda data storage options in web apps](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-aws-lambda-data-storage-options-in-web-apps/)
- [Amazon S3 Node.js Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-node-examples.html)
- [Deploy Node.js Lambda functions with .zip file archives](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html)
- [AWS Serverless Application Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html)

Hope this helps